# Date in format of YYYYMMDD rather than YYYY-MM-DD in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

The files I need to move has a pattern of date like this: `20190328`.

My datetime module gives me the date as `YYYY-MM-DD`. How can I get the date in form `YYYYMMDD`?

Comment: Post the sample which is giving you `2019-03-28`

Comment: `print (str.replace("-",""))` ?? Like [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/rkgkC-c_4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`strftime`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm):

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
20190328
```